How to avoid "RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10" in a for loop with over 20.000 elements?
I have a list of data called data. This list contains 21073 nested numpy arrays. Each numpy array, in turn, contains 512 values. Paradigmatially, one nested numpy array looks as follows:
[534.42623424, 942.2323, 123.73434 ...].
Moreover, I have another list of data called freq:
freq = [0.0009, 0.0053, 0.0034 ...] which is also 512 digits long.
Aim:
I use a for loop to compute a linear least-square regression via scipy.linregress(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) between each nested numpy array in list and freq as follows:
for i in data:
slope = sp.stats.linregress(x=np.log10(freq), y=np.log10(i))[0]

The code works. But there is one problem.
Problem: I assume that due to the massive size of the for loop (= 21073) I always get the error RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10. Importantly, the position in the for loop where this error occurs varies every time I run the code again. That is, sometimes it occurs at n = 512, then again close to the end at n = 18766.
Question: Am I right that the problem is related to the massive size of the for loop. How can I fix the problem?

Any code susceptible to throw an exception should be inside a try block. Just put it inside a try and handle the exception

Can you give an example of a 512 digit float? Note that the "error" isn't actually an error - it's a warning. np.log10(0) == -inf There's obviously a zero in one or other of your arrays. The issue has nothing to do with the size of your list

@SIGHUP, two points. First, if there is a zero in one (or more) of the single arrays, then why does the problem not occur at the exact same position every time I run the code again? Shouldn't the problem occur at the exact same position (within the for loop) if it was really related to taking the log of zero, i.e., np.log10(0)? Second, I checked the data, and there is no zero value at the positions where I get the warning. So the problem does not stem from taking the log of zero. Finally, sorry about 512 digit float, I only meant to say that each array contains 512 values.

freq is always the same, i changes.

You problem has nothing to do with the size of your data array. The warning is issued because one or other of your arrays contains one or more zeroes.
You can suppress the warning but you have to consider the impact this will have on your results.
For example:
import numpy as np
assert np.log10(0) == -np.inf

The log10 operations are vectorised and do not therefore align (as you might expect) with your loop index.
You should not calculate the np.log10(freq) at every iteration of the loop because it wastes valuable time. It will always return the same result.
Consider this:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress
from time import perf_counter

np.seterr(all="ignore")

N = 21_073

data = [np.random.rand(512) for _ in range(N)]
freq = [np.random.rand(512)]

x = np.log10(freq)

if 0 in x:
    print("freq contains at least one zero value. Results may not be as expected")

start = perf_counter()

for datum in data:
    if 0 in datum:
        print("datum contains at least one zero value, Results may not be as expected")
    slope = linregress(x=x, y=np.log10(datum)).slope # type: ignore

print(f"Duration={perf_counter()-start:.4f}s")

Output:
Duration=0.6616s


Thanks for your help. One question remains. Why does RuntimeWarning never occur at the same iteration in the loop? What I mean to say is that the RuntimeWarning divide by zero encountered in log10 sometimes occurs at 18488/21073, then again at 20132/21073. When I then check the 512 value array at those specific positions, it never is 0. I don't understand where this warning comes from then. I now bypass this problem via data[data == 0] = np.finfo(float).eps, hence changing the value close to zero where the warning occurs. But this is not optimal of course.

@Philipp I'm not expert on numpy but I believe this is due to the underlying vectorisation mechanism - i.e., the array values are not necessarily operated on in a linear fashion. The real issue here is that you should be checking your arrays to ensure that they contain appropriate values for calculating a slope. If you don't, then the answer(s) are likely to be meaningless or, at the very least, inaccurate

Thanks so much. I finally understood the source of the problem. Sorry, it took a while. The problem RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log occurs when only one single value (in the 512 value array) is zero. I always thought the error only occurs when the whole array is zero. Note: the 512 value array stems from a power spectrum (FFT). So in one or two arrays there are bins that are zero, and then the RuntimeWarning occurs. I finally get it.

Note one way of dealing with this (especially if you're only interested in the slope) is to add a small value to you Y's so that they're all > 0 (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.11820.pdf). You can do this by taking the min of vector then adding that and a bit more.

Try this:
for i in range(len(list)):
  slope = sp.stats.linregress(x=np.log10(freq[i]), y=np.log10(list[i]))[0]

and also consider changing the variable name 'list'.

np.log10(freq[i]) breaks the intention of the original code
